# Cannot create a channel in Hyper-ledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

**Problem:**

I am new to the blockchain. I am creating an application using Hyperledger. After setup the network when I am going to create channel It leaves me this output on the terminal.

```
2019-03-13 17:06:58.625 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 001 Found map[string]interface{} value for peer.BCCSP
2019-03-13 17:06:58.625 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 002 Found map[string]interface{} value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11
2019-03-13 17:06:58.626 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 003 Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: <nil>
2019-03-13 17:06:58.627 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 004 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.Pin setting to <nil> <nil>
2019-03-13 17:06:58.627 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 005 Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: <nil>
2019-03-13 17:06:58.628 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 006 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.Hash
setting to <nil> <nil>
2019-03-13 17:06:58.628 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 007 Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: <nil>
2019-03-13 17:06:58.629 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 008 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.Security setting to <nil> <nil>
2019-03-13 17:06:58.629 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 009 Found map[string]interface{} value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.FileKeyStore
2019-03-13 17:06:58.630 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 00a Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: <nil>
2019-03-13 17:06:58.630 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 00b Found real value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.FileKeyStore.KeyStore setting to <nil> <nil>
2019-03-13 17:06:58.631 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 00c Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: <nil>
2019-03-13 17:06:58.631 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 00d Found real value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.Library setting to <nil> <nil>
2019-03-13 17:06:58.632 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 00e Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: <nil>
2019-03-13 17:06:58.632 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 00f Found real value for peer.BCCSP.PKCS11.Label setting to <nil> <nil>
2019-03-13 17:06:58.633 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 010 Unmarshal JSON: value cannot be unmarshalled: invalid character 'S' looking for beginning of value
2019-03-13 17:06:58.633 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 011 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.Default setting to string SW
2019-03-13 17:06:58.633 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 012 Found map[string]interface{} value for peer.BCCSP.SW
2019-03-13 17:06:58.633 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 013 Unmarshal JSON: value cannot be unmarshalled: invalid character 'S' looking for beginning of value
2019-03-13 17:06:58.633 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 014 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.SW.Hash setting to string SHA2
2019-03-13 17:06:58.634 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 015 Unmarshal JSON: value is not a string: 256
2019-03-13 17:06:58.634 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 016 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.SW.Security
setting to int 256
2019-03-13 17:06:58.634 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 017 Found map[string]interface{} value for peer.BCCSP.SW.FileKeyStore
2019-03-13 17:06:58.634 UTC [viperutil] unmarshalJSON -> DEBU 018 Unmarshal JSON: value cannot be unmarshalled: unexpected end of JSON input
2019-03-13 17:06:58.634 UTC [viperutil] getKeysRecursively -> DEBU 019 Found real value for peer.BCCSP.SW.FileKeyStore.KeyStore setting to string
2019-03-13 17:06:58.634 UTC [viperutil] EnhancedExactUnmarshalKey -> DEBU 01a map[peer.BCCSP:map[PKCS11:map[Label:<nil> Pin:<nil> Hash:<nil> Security:<nil> FileKeyStore:map[KeyStore:<nil>] Library:<nil>] Default:SW SW:map[Hash:SHA2 Security:256 FileKeyStore:map[KeyStore:]]]]
2019-03-13 17:06:58.637 UTC [bccsp_sw] openKeyStore -> DEBU 01b KeyStore opened at [/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/slpolice.trafficfine.com/users/Admin@slpolice.trafficfine.com/msp/keystore]...done
2019-03-13 17:06:58.637 UTC [bccsp] initBCCSP -> DEBU 01c Initialize BCCSP [SW]
2019-03-13 17:06:58.638 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 01d Reading directory /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/slpolice.trafficfine.com/users/Admin@slpolice.trafficfine.com/msp/signcerts
2019-03-13 17:06:58.641 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 01e Inspecting file /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/slpolice.trafficfine.com/users/Admin@slpolice.trafficfine.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@slpolice.trafficfine.com-cert.pem
2019-03-13 17:06:58.643 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 01f Reading directory /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/slpolice.trafficfine.com/users/Admin@slpolice.trafficfine.com/msp/cacerts
2019-03-13 17:06:58.647 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 020 Inspecting file /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/slpolice.trafficfine.com/users/Admin@slpolice.trafficfine.com/msp/cacerts/ca.slpolice.trafficfine.com-cert.pem
2019-03-13 17:06:58.649 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 021 Reading directory /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/slpolice.trafficfine.com/users/Admin@slpolice.trafficfine.com/msp/admincerts
2019-03-13 17:06:58.653 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 022 Inspecting file /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/slpolice.trafficfine.com/users/Admin@slpolice.trafficfine.com/msp/admincerts/Admin@slpolice.trafficfine.com-cert.pem
2019-03-13 17:06:58.656 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 023 Reading directory /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/slpolice.trafficfine.com/users/Admin@slpolice.trafficfine.com/msp/intermediatecerts
2019-03-13 17:06:58.657 UTC [msp] getMspConfig -> DEBU 024 Intermediate certs folder not found at [/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/slpolice.trafficfine.com/users/Admin@slpolice.trafficfine.com/msp/intermediatecerts]. Skipping. [stat /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/slpolice.trafficfine.com/users/Admin@slpolice.trafficfine.com/msp/intermediatecerts: no such file or directory]
2019-03-13 17:06:58.657 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 025 Reading directory /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/slpolice.trafficfine.com/users/Admin@slpolice.trafficfine.com/msp/tlscacerts
2019-03-13 17:06:58.661 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 026 Inspecting file /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/slpolice.trafficfine.com/users/Admin@slpolice.trafficfine.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.slpolice.trafficfine.com-cert.pem
2019-03-13 17:06:58.664 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 027 Reading directory /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/slpolice.trafficfine.com/users/Admin@slpolice.trafficfine.com/msp/tlsintermediatecerts
2019-03-13 17:06:58.665 UTC [msp] getMspConfig -> DEBU 028 TLS intermediate certs folder not found at [/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/slpolice.trafficfine.com/users/Admin@slpolice.trafficfine.com/msp/tlsintermediatecerts]. Skipping. [stat /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/slpolice.trafficfine.com/users/Admin@slpolice.trafficfine.com/msp/tlsintermediatecerts: no such file or directory]
2019-03-13 17:06:58.665 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 029 Reading directory /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/slpolice.trafficfine.com/users/Admin@slpolice.trafficfine.com/msp/crls
2019-03-13 17:06:58.666 UTC [msp] getMspConfig -> DEBU 02a crls folder not found at [/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/slpolice.trafficfine.com/users/Admin@slpolice.trafficfine.com/msp/crls]. Skipping. [stat /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/slpolice.trafficfine.com/users/Admin@slpolice.trafficfine.com/msp/crls: no such file or directory]
2019-03-13 17:06:58.668 UTC [msp] getMspConfig -> DEBU 02b MSP configuration file not found at [/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/slpolice.trafficfine.com/users/Admin@slpolice.trafficfine.com/msp/config.yaml]: [stat /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/slpolice.trafficfine.com/users/Admin@slpolice.trafficfine.com/msp/config.yaml: no such file or directory]
2019-03-13 17:06:58.668 UTC [msp] newBccspMsp -> DEBU 02c Creating BCCSP-based MSP instance
2019-03-13 17:06:58.668 UTC [msp] New -> DEBU 02d Creating Cache-MSP instance
2019-03-13 17:06:58.670 UTC [msp] loadLocaMSP -> DEBU 02e Created new local MSP
2019-03-13 17:06:58.670 UTC [msp] Setup -> DEBU 02f Setting up MSP instance SLpoliceMSP
2019-03-13 17:06:58.671 UTC [msp.identity] newIdentity -> DEBU 030 Creating identity instance for cert -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
2019-03-13 17:06:58.671 UTC [msp.identity] newIdentity -> DEBU 031 Creating identity instance for cert -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIICQjCCAemgAwIBAgIQJsApcoa4cJUrPits3jp+QzAKBggqhkjOPQQDAjCBgzEL
MAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEzARBgNVBAgTCkNhbGlmb3JuaWExFjAUBgNVBAcTDVNhbiBG
cmFuY2lzY28xITAfBgNVBAoTGHNscG9saWNlLnRyYWZmaWNmaW5lLmNvbTEkMCIG
A1UEAxMbY2Euc2xwb2xpY2UudHJhZmZpY2ZpbmUuY29tMB4XDTE5MDMwNzA2MjQw
MFoXDTI5MDMwNDA2MjQwMFowdDELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEzARBgNVBAgTCkNhbGlm
b3JuaWExFjAUBgNVBAcTDVNhbiBGcmFuY2lzY28xDzANBgNVBAsTBmNsaWVudDEn
MCUGA1UEAwweQWRtaW5Ac2xwb2xpY2UudHJhZmZpY2ZpbmUuY29tMFkwEwYHKoZI
zj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEn6t3WpbESUiAT32WFEl1ZmzSxfgGZO/zm9kdlCwS
V8d15HWUrqk6xYByoViKuxaEvgoCFqJdt8seWZJkbMhVqqNNMEswDgYDVR0PAQH/
BAQDAgeAMAwGA1UdEwEB/wQCMAAwKwYDVR0jBCQwIoAgax6WyeKGFdOQCgdIgd57
yqWMNyg9qUdwj11oXdR6q8MwCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIDRwAwRAIgUzZ+Ao6wFqzTzcpK
CCrSJffiKIdm4MLAmwAQNd6QY0ICIHhprcZhka3PUfa+48+DJfHOh4AWPIrL0q9h
8tgF7Tmu
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
2019-03-13 17:06:58.687 UTC [msp.identity] newIdentity -> DEBU 032 Creating identity instance for cert -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
2019-03-13 17:06:58.690 UTC [bccsp_sw] loadPrivateKey -> DEBU 033 Loading private key [1456180abdcceb28bf0485480d2a2d51ab606b453fcdbbe9e0d2a932a8584bfd] at [/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/slpolice.trafficfine.com/users/Admin@slpolice.trafficfine.com/msp/keystore/1456180abdcceb28bf0485480d2a2d51ab606b453fcdbbe9e0d2a932a8584bfd_sk]...
2019-03-13 17:06:58.694 UTC [msp.identity] newIdentity -> DEBU 034 Creating identity instance for cert -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
2019-03-13 17:06:58.694 UTC [msp] setupSigningIdentity -> DEBU 035 Signing identity expires at 2029-03-04 06:24:00
+0000 UTC
2019-03-13 17:06:58.695 UTC [msp] Validate -> DEBU 036 MSP SLpoliceMSP validating identity
2019-03-13 17:06:58.695 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 037 Obtaining default signing identity
2019-03-13 17:06:58.708 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 038 parsed scheme: ""
2019-03-13 17:06:58.708 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 039 scheme "" not registered, fallback to default scheme
2019-03-13 17:06:58.708 UTC [grpc] watcher -> DEBU 03a ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{orderer.trafficfine.com:7050 0  <nil>}]
2019-03-13 17:06:58.708 UTC [grpc] switchBalancer -> DEBU 03b ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
2019-03-13 17:06:58.709 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 03c pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0003edb10, CONNECTING
2019-03-13 17:06:58.719 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 03d pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0003edb10, READY
2019-03-13 17:06:58.719 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 03e Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2019-03-13 17:06:58.724 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 03f Obtaining default signing identity
2019-03-13 17:06:58.724 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 040 Obtaining default signing identity
2019-03-13 17:06:58.725 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 041 Sign: plaintext: 0ADB060A0B534C706F6C6963654D5350...696366696E65436F6E736F727469756D
2019-03-13 17:06:58.725 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 042 Sign: digest: 1641D1573EB4A7102008B103534E5D593955C26C8430255B4F029A9AE4B4AE6F
2019-03-13 17:06:58.725 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 043 Obtaining default signing identity
2019-03-13 17:06:58.725 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 044 Obtaining default signing identity
2019-03-13 17:06:58.725 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 045 Sign: plaintext: 0A94070A1708021A0608B2F1A4E40522...9CC9656F67BEE8870E72BA0FD7D975D4
2019-03-13 17:06:58.725 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 046 Sign: digest: 5539593EDC889AACFD13B9E45F85DACA12A7C77E084DA74CA73F681BF16E892D
2019-03-13 17:06:58.729 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 047 parsed scheme: ""
2019-03-13 17:06:58.729 UTC [grpc] DialContext -> DEBU 048 scheme "" not registered, fallback to default scheme
2019-03-13 17:06:58.729 UTC [grpc] watcher -> DEBU 049 ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{orderer.trafficfine.com:7050 0  <nil>}]
2019-03-13 17:06:58.729 UTC [grpc] switchBalancer -> DEBU 04a ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
2019-03-13 17:06:58.729 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 04b pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc00021f2e0, CONNECTING
2019-03-13 17:06:58.735 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 04c pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc00021f2e0, READY
Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Group]  /Channel/Application not satisfied: Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining
```

Here I am providing the logs of the orderer.

```
2019-03-13 16:50:39.871 UTC [localconfig] completeInitialization -> INFO 001 Kafka.Version unset, setting to 0.10.2.0
2019-03-13 16:50:40.220 UTC [orderer.common.server] prettyPrintStruct -> INFO 002 Orderer config values:
        General.LedgerType = "file"
        General.ListenAddress = "0.0.0.0"
        General.ListenPort = 7050
        General.TLS.Enabled = true
        General.TLS.PrivateKey = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key"
        General.TLS.Certificate = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt"
        General.TLS.RootCAs = [/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
        General.TLS.ClientAuthRequired = false
        General.TLS.ClientRootCAs = []
        General.Cluster.RootCAs = [/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt]
        General.Cluster.ClientCertificate = ""
        General.Cluster.ClientPrivateKey = ""
        General.Cluster.DialTimeout = 5s
        General.Cluster.RPCTimeout = 7s
        General.Cluster.ReplicationBufferSize = 20971520
        General.Cluster.ReplicationPullTimeout = 5s
        General.Cluster.ReplicationRetryTimeout = 5s
        General.Keepalive.ServerMinInterval = 1m0s
        General.Keepalive.ServerInterval = 2h0m0s
        General.Keepalive.ServerTimeout = 20s
        General.GenesisMethod = "file"
        General.GenesisProfile = "SampleInsecureSolo"
        General.SystemChannel = "test-system-channel-name"
        General.GenesisFile = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block"
        General.Profile.Enabled = false
        General.Profile.Address = "0.0.0.0:6060"
        General.LocalMSPDir = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp"
        General.LocalMSPID = "OrdererMSP"
        General.BCCSP.ProviderName = "SW"
        General.BCCSP.SwOpts.SecLevel = 256
        General.BCCSP.SwOpts.HashFamily = "SHA2"
        General.BCCSP.SwOpts.Ephemeral = false
        General.BCCSP.SwOpts.FileKeystore.KeyStorePath = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp/keystore"
        General.BCCSP.SwOpts.DummyKeystore =
        General.BCCSP.SwOpts.InmemKeystore =
        General.BCCSP.PluginOpts =
        General.Authentication.TimeWindow = 15m0s
        FileLedger.Location = "/var/hyperledger/production/orderer"
        FileLedger.Prefix = "hyperledger-fabric-ordererledger"
        RAMLedger.HistorySize = 1000
        Kafka.Retry.ShortInterval = 5s
        Kafka.Retry.ShortTotal = 10m0s
        Kafka.Retry.LongInterval = 5m0s
        Kafka.Retry.LongTotal = 12h0m0s
        Kafka.Retry.NetworkTimeouts.DialTimeout = 10s
        Kafka.Retry.NetworkTimeouts.ReadTimeout = 10s
        Kafka.Retry.NetworkTimeouts.WriteTimeout = 10s
        Kafka.Retry.Metadata.RetryMax = 3
        Kafka.Retry.Metadata.RetryBackoff = 250ms
        Kafka.Retry.Producer.RetryMax = 3
        Kafka.Retry.Producer.RetryBackoff = 100ms
        Kafka.Retry.Consumer.RetryBackoff = 2s
        Kafka.Verbose = false
        Kafka.Version = 0.10.2.0
        Kafka.TLS.Enabled = false
        Kafka.TLS.PrivateKey = ""
        Kafka.TLS.Certificate = ""
        Kafka.TLS.RootCAs = []
        Kafka.TLS.ClientAuthRequired = false
        Kafka.TLS.ClientRootCAs = []
        Kafka.SASLPlain.Enabled = false
        Kafka.SASLPlain.User = ""
        Kafka.SASLPlain.Password = ""
        Kafka.Topic.ReplicationFactor = 3
        Debug.BroadcastTraceDir = ""
        Debug.DeliverTraceDir = ""
        Consensus = map[WALDir:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer/etcdraft/wal SnapDir:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer/etcdraft/snapshot]
        Operations.ListenAddress = "127.0.0.1:8443"
        Operations.TLS.Enabled = false
        Operations.TLS.PrivateKey = ""
        Operations.TLS.Certificate = ""
        Operations.TLS.RootCAs = []
        Operations.TLS.ClientAuthRequired = false
        Operations.TLS.ClientRootCAs = []
        Metrics.Provider = "disabled"
        Metrics.Statsd.Network = "udp"
        Metrics.Statsd.Address = "127.0.0.1:8125"
        Metrics.Statsd.WriteInterval = 30s
        Metrics.Statsd.Prefix = ""
2019-03-13 16:50:41.899 UTC [orderer.common.server] initializeServerConfig -> INFO 003 Starting orderer with TLS enabled
2019-03-13 16:50:41.993 UTC [fsblkstorage] newBlockfileMgr -> INFO 004 Getting block information from block storage
2019-03-13 16:50:43.606 UTC [orderer.commmon.multichannel] Initialize -> INFO 005 Starting system channel 'byfn-sys-channel' with genesis block hash 354fad4b4ce9938dba9ab9d750cf08c34b3aa0057012a77a60a2fb94fa65c481 and orderer type solo
2019-03-13 16:50:43.607 UTC [orderer.common.server] Start -> INFO 006 Starting orderer:
 Version: 1.4.0
 Commit SHA: d700b43
 Go version: go1.11.1
 OS/Arch: linux/amd64
2019-03-13 16:50:43.607 UTC [orderer.common.server] Start -> INFO 007 Beginning to serve requests
2019-03-13 16:52:25.460 UTC [orderer.common.broadcast] ProcessMessage -> WARN 008 [channel: trafficfine] Rejecting broadcast of config message from 172.19.0.21:53566 because of error: error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Group]  /Channel/Application not satisfied: Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining
2019-03-13 16:52:25.460 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 009 streaming call completed {"grpc.start_time": "2019-03-13T16:52:25.421Z", "grpc.service": "orderer.AtomicBroadcast", "grpc.method": "Broadcast", "grpc.peer_address": "172.19.0.21:53566", "grpc.code": "OK", "grpc.call_duration": "38.6993ms"}
2019-03-13 16:52:25.483 UTC [common.deliver] Handle -> WARN 00a Error reading from 172.19.0.21:53564: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2019-03-13 16:52:25.484 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 00b streaming call completed {"grpc.start_time": "2019-03-13T16:52:25.416Z", "grpc.service": "orderer.AtomicBroadcast", "grpc.method": "Deliver", "grpc.peer_address": "172.19.0.21:53564", "error": "rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled", "grpc.code": "Canceled", "grpc.call_duration": "68.1955ms"}
2019-03-13 17:06:58.765 UTC [orderer.common.broadcast] ProcessMessage -> WARN 00c [channel: trafficfine] Rejecting broadcast of config message from 172.19.0.21:53570 because of error: error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Group]  /Channel/Application not satisfied: Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining
2019-03-13 17:06:58.765 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 00d streaming call completed {"grpc.start_time": "2019-03-13T17:06:58.737Z", "grpc.service": "orderer.AtomicBroadcast", "grpc.method": "Broadcast", "grpc.peer_address": "172.19.0.21:53570", "grpc.code": "OK", "grpc.call_duration": "28.1769ms"}
2019-03-13 17:06:58.780 UTC [common.deliver] Handle -> WARN 00e Error reading from 172.19.0.21:53568: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2019-03-13 17:06:58.780 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 00f streaming call completed {"grpc.start_time": "2019-03-13T17:06:58.721Z", "grpc.service": "orderer.AtomicBroadcast", "grpc.method": "Deliver", "grpc.peer_address": "172.19.0.21:53568", "error": "rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled", "grpc.code": "Canceled", "grpc.call_duration": "59.2509ms"}
```

Can someone help me to solve this problem? I have tried all the options given by similar questions but I am completely helpless with this error.

Answer (score 0):

This error message brings the main issue regarding the policy in the configtx.yaml

> policy for [Group]  /Channel/Application not satisfied: Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining

if you already defined the orderer policy like below change is accordinly and generate the crypto one more time and run the network.

```
   Policies:
    #    Readers:
    #        Type: Signature
    #        Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
    #    Writers:
    #        Type: Signature
    #        Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
    #    Admins:
    #        Type: Signature
    #        Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.admin')"
    Policies:
     Readers:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "ANY Readers"
     Writers:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "ANY Writers"
     Admins:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
```